# Central List for multiple libraries

Tags: 2013, list, document-library, records-center

I'm new to SharePoint and have been able to fumble my way through a lot learning as I go by watching tutorials and making mistakes but I'm having a difficult time with my latest problem.  I'm running SharePoint 2013 Enterprise.

I have a user that wants to store confidential information in different libraries that have different permission settings.  I thought the a Record Center page would be really good for this as they aren't documents they would need for everyday use.  I've got a test page setup to let people submit documents that will be directed to the appropriate library via their selection.

What I want is to have a list that pulls information from the libraries in the site to create a central area to view all documents that dynamically updates with the libraries.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is such a thing already built in, but it has more than what you are looking for.

Addresses can be manually changed to go to _Layouts/sitemanager.aspx

for example I go to my team site:
https://Cant.tell.com/sites1/is/SitePages/Home.aspx

Change the url like this:
https://Cant.tell.com/sites1/is/_Layouts/sitemanager.aspx

If I don't have permissions it teases me with a bunch of things I can't do, but it is there.

You can get there for a site by going to Site actions -> Manage Content and structure

It is intended to be a administrative tool for managing stuff, so you wouldn't want to give this to end users if you have over-granted their permissions. Also, security by obscurity doesn't work, so even if you don't want people to go here, they *could*. So perhaps this is a quick way to check off a requirement.

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for.  I'll try to clarify:
User A submits Record A for Group A, User B submits Record B for Group B, and User C Submits Record C for Group C.  Record Center sorts all of these to Libraries A, B, and C via organizer rules.  Site Admin, also a "normal" user, wants a list that shows all records from Libraries A, B, and C without having to visit each library separately.
I may have to play around with Designer to get this to work the way I want.  I'm not sure though.  Like I said I'm a noob with SharePoint anything.

Answer (score 1):

You could try playing around with the [Content Query Web Part](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650512.aspx). It enables you to roll up content based on location or content type into one page.